# Creating a UILabel copy without using the original label

Tags: iphone, objective-c, copy, uilabel

I'm pretty new to iPhone programming. I seem to have encountered a bug that I can't solve. I have a set of UILabels that I display on a large label. When a certain button is hit, I display these labels on a UITableView. However when I do this, the labels that were originally displayed on the large label disappear. I figured, this is probably because I've changed the frame and hence the labels shift positions. To solve this, I tried saving the labels into another array and using that array instead to display in the table view. Still no luck. Please help! Also, how do I store a label in another temporary UILabel?

Comment: Why do you need to store a UILabel in another UILabel? Are you trying to display custom labels in TableView cell?

Comment: Because I want to display the same labels in two different places.

Answer (score 1):

An `UILabel` is a view. Don't store your data (`NSString`s) in there, but put it in your model (or controller if it's transient data) classes. Then, when you need to display the data, create the views (`UILabel`s in your case) to show it.